# On a convergent and divergent Picard iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I have searched for a similar question, but I haven't found any question that shows how the successive approximations might actually diverge despite the solution being defined there, which is what I'm after with the following IVP: $$x'=1+(x-t)^2,\quad x(0)=0.$$ There should be some number $a>0$ such that the successive approximations diverge when $|t|>a$, yet I haven't been able to find one.

For an example of the method of successive approximations, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Example_of_Picard_iteration). In this case we have

\begin{align}
&x_0(t)=x(0)=0,\\ 
&x_1(t)=x_0(t)+\int_0^t \big(1+(x_0(s)-s)\big)^2ds=t+\frac{t^3}{3}, \\ 
&x_2(t)=x_0(t)+\int_0^t \big(1+(x_1(s)-s)\big)^2ds=t+\frac{t^7}{3^27}, \\
&\cdots .
\end{align}

You can verify by induction that we get, $$x_k(t)=t+\frac{t^{2^{k+1}-1}}{(2^2-1)^{2^{k-1}}(2^3-1)^{2^{k-2}}\cdots(2^{k+1}-1)}.\tag1$$

By inspection, I think the second term goes to $0$ for $|t|\leq 1$. And $x(t)=t$ is indeed a solution of the IVP. However, what about divergence? Does the numerator grow faster than the denominator for $|t|>1$? I am only looking for *some* number $a$ such that $(1)$ diverges for $|t|>a$.

I note the following. If we denote the second term in $(1)$ by $e_k(t)$, then $$e_k(t)=\frac{(e_{k-1}(t))^2 t}{(2^{k+1}-1)}\geq \frac{(e_{k-1}(t))^2 t}{2^{k+1}}.$$ Maybe this inequality is helpful in bounding $e_k(t)$ further, but I'm not sure how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$ holds for $k=1,2,\ldots$ and so $e_k(t)$ is a sequence of functions going from $k=1,2,\ldots$. To show it diverges for some $|t|>a$, where $a>0$, we can try bounding it from below by a sequence of functions that diverges to $\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ for $|t|>a$.

If $e_k(t)$ were to increase by a factor of $\alpha>1$, i.e. $$e_{k+1}(t)\geq \alpha e_{k}(t),\quad k=1,2\ldots\tag2$$ then $e_{k+1}(t)\geq \alpha^k e_{1}(t)$. For the $t's$ that satisfy $(2)$ and for which $e_1(t)\neq 0$, we will have $\alpha^ke_1(t)\to \infty$ as $k\to\infty$, and so $e_{k+1}(t)\to\infty$ for those $t$. We could still have divergence for $e_1(t)=0$, but we see that this is not possible since $e_1(t)=0$ only for $t=0$, in which case $e_{k}(0)=0$. It is also assumed that $e_k(t)$ is positive. If it were negative, change $\geq$ to $\leq$ in $(2)$; we'll arrive at the same result below.

So, using the relation between $e_k(t)$ and $e_{k-1}(t)$ in the question above, $(2)$ reads $$e_k(t)=\frac{(e_{k-1}(t))^2 t}{(2^{k+1}-1)}\geq \alpha e_{k-1}(t)\quad k=2,3,\ldots.$$ $e_k(t)=0$ only for $t=0$, in which case we have convergence. So if $t\neq 0$, we can divide the above inequality by $e_{k-1}(t)$. After rearranging, we get $$e_{k-1}(t) t\geq (2^{k+1}-1)\alpha .$$ We are looking for $t$'s that satisfy the above inequality. Put $k=2$ and we get after rearranging $$t^4\geq 21\alpha,$$ or $|t|\geq\sqrt[4]{21\alpha}>\sqrt[4]{21}$.